# Qt qml running too slow

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am using olimex A20Lime2 board with Linux OS. I have created Qt QML desktop application using qt 5.3.2 with QtQuick2. My application needs to update qml gui on every 100 ms but it takes 2-3 secs to update it as well as when button is clicked it takes 4-5 secs to change the color of button or change the image.

I have used C++ as much as possible. And updating qml items such as Text by using signal and slot methods. Overall working of qml UI is too slow. How can make it more fast?

Comment: Do you mind posting some code ?

Comment: Be more specific about your os. Did you build Linux yourself with yocto? What window manager are you using? If you are trying to run Debian, gnome, and QML then it will be slow, there isn't enough ram! Have you got a fast SD card?

Comment: I am using debian jessie  on 16gb class 10 sd card. Is there any other way to make it faster?

Comment: I am really sorry , I cant post code

Comment: We're you given a choice of desktop environment when you first booted Debian? Choice is usually Gnome, KDE, LXDE, Xfce, etc. Gnome and KDE use the most RAM. I am not sure 512MB is enough for Debian, Gnome and Qt. Please can you check out your RAM usage while your Qt app is running and post some info please

Comment: No , there were no choices, I am using official debian image of A20Lime2, but I think this one is using Gnome.                                                                         A20Lime2 board has 1GB DDR3 RAM memory.                                            Regarding RAM usage, it shows 87% of cpu utilization and 7.7% of memory.